# Why icon can not be dispalyed corrent in css defination

Tags: css

In my project, i want to use a icon, here is html code:

```
 <span class="item-title-icon"></span>
```

and here is defination of icon:

```
.item-title-icon
  position: relative
  left: .06rem
  top: .06rem
  display: inline-block
  width: .36rem
  height: .36rem
  background-size: .4rem 3rem
  background: url(http://s.qunarzz.com/piao/image/touch/sight/detail.png) 0 -.45rem no-repeat
  margin-right: .1rem
```

unlucky, It display wrong, the icon can not display correct, only part of it displays. And it seems nothing wrong, who can help me ?

Comment: Have you tried removing background-position from `background` or adjust it to correct values?

Comment: @Justinas, what is background-position?

Comment: The `0 -.45rem` after `url()` part in `background:` rule

Comment: @Justinas, Yes, I have tested about removing 0 -.45rem, but it works fail again

Answer (score 0):

It seems your width was to small for the image to get fully displayed.

```
width: .36rem
height: .36rem
```

https://jsfiddle.net/votrq7hn/